# How to set autofocus on input in Safari (react app)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

Input autofocus normal work on androids, but doesn't work in Safari on iphones.

**input.focus()** doesn't help.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware autofocus is not supported on Safari iOS.

[Source](https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=195884#c4)

Comment: it suppose to be a comment

Comment: I can't add comments yet unfortunately so that was the only way I could try to help.